# How do I render a base64-encoded image in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64

I have a base64-encoded JPG in my app, and I'd like to render that image as a JPG in a controller.

Answer (score 7):

I worked this out as soon as I asked the question. Assuming you have the base64 string in `@image_data`:

```
send_data Base64.decode64(@image_data),
  :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it with the usual `render` syntax:

```
render text: Base64.decode64(your_base_64_string),
       content_type: 'image/jpeg'
```

Comment: I *think* `text` is now `plain` in Rails 5.2+ at least.